# Redisson Delayed Queue using the reactive client

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, redisson

I was checking the RDelayedQueue implementation provided by Redisson and was able to run it properly in a non reactive environment. But while using the reactive client, I am able to only view Blocking And Transfer Queue options.
Why does not Redisson support Delayed Queue in reactive environment?
What can be a possible workaround for the same.
The idea is to act on an object after a certain timeout value which would be the delay.

Note: I am using Redisson free version 3.23.5